# Why don't the \chead and \pagestyle commands affect page headers in the \pagecommand of the pdfpages package?

Tags: header-footer, pdfpages

I want to include about 500-600 pdf files of a scientific conference in a root file. My root file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\conftitle}{The 7th International Conference on...}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[R]{LOGO}
\fancyhead[C]{\conftitle}
\fancyhead[L]{\thepage}
}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\pagestyle{mystyle}\chead{\conftitle \\ First article title}}]{pdf-1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\pagestyle{mystyle}\chead{\conftitle\\ Second article title}}]{pdf-2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The codes that produces `pdf-1.pdf` and `pdf-2.pdf` are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{The first Paper}
\author{John Doe}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1-17]
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{The Second Paper}
\author{Joe Smith}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[6-18]
\end{document}
```

But as you see on the output, the `\pagestyle{mystyle}` and `\chead{\conftitle \\ First article title}` commands don't affect the headers at all. I want my header, for example, for the first included pdf to be like the following screenshot:
[image]

**How can I solve this problem?**
P.s.: I know that with the following code, I can fix the problem, but I want to do this using the `\pagecommand` command or other alternative options of the `\includepdf` command.

```
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\chead{\conftitle\\ First sample article title}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\pagestyle{mystyle}\chead{\conftitle \\ First article title}}]{pdf-1.pdf}
\chead{\conftitle\\ second sample article title}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\pagestyle{mystyle}\chead{\conftitle\\ Second article title}}]{pdf-2.pdf}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, that `\pagestyle{}` inside a `pagecommand` is useless, but defining separate styles for the articles will work, then issueing an per-page `\thispagestyle{articlestyle}` does the job.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\conftitle}{The 7th International Conference on...}
\fancypagestyle{firstpaperstyle}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[R]{LOGO}
\fancyhead[C]{\conftitle}
\fancyhead[L]{\thepage}
\chead{\conftitle\\ First article title}%

}


\fancypagestyle{secondpaperstyle}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[R]{LOGO}
\fancyhead[C]{\conftitle}
\fancyhead[L]{\thepage}
\chead{\conftitle\\ Second article title}%
}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{firstpaperstyle}}]{pdf-1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{secondpaperstyle}}]{pdf-2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'll try to figure out, why `\pagestyle` itself does not work.

This approach might not be an option if many article papers have to be included

**Edit**

Obviously, it's an expansion problem with `\chead`, so it's better to do an `on-the-fly` adjustment of the conference - article title header.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\conftitle}{The 7th International Conference on...}

\gdef\realconftitle{\conftitle}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[R]{LOGO}
\fancyhead[C]{\realconftitle}
\fancyhead[L]{\thepage}
}

\newcommand{\adjustconftitle}[1]{%
  \gdef\realconftitle{\conftitle \\ #1}%
}%


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mystyle}%
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\adjustconftitle{First article title}\pagestyle{mystyle}}]{pdf-1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\adjustconftitle{Second article title}\pagestyle{mystyle}}]{pdf-2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but as you mentioned, I have about 500-600 pdfs and so defining a style for each of them is very time-consuming.

Comment: @Sisabe: I found another approach, easier, but you still have to adjust the titles, but you knew that before, right? ;-)